# Activeadmin, duplicating has_many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

When I use ActiveAdmin to edit one Agency, I can select a City and associates it to the Agency. The city is linked to the Agency, but the city is all the times duplicated in the database.

My models:

```
# agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agency_cities
  has_many :cities, through: :agency_cities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities, allow_destroy: true
end

# city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agency_cities
  has_many :agencies, through: :agency_cities
end

# AgencyCity.rb
class AgencyCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I read the doc of `Activeadmin` and added the `[:id] permit_parameter`, but I still have the problem, I'm very confused.

```
# admin/agency.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
  permit_params :name, :picture,
    cities_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :_destroy]

  form do |f|
     f.inputs "Agencies" do
       f.input :picture, as: :file
       f.input :creation_date, label: 'Creation Date'
       f.input :name, label: 'Name'
     end
   end

   f.inputs do
     f.has_many :cities do |k|
       k.input :name, label: 'City',
         as: :select,
         collection: City.all.map{ |u| "#{u.name}"}
       k.input :_destroy, as: :boolean
     end
   end
   f.actions
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You are trying to associate the existing cities with an agency, so, you should do it this way:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agency do
  permit_params city_ids: [] # You need to whitelist the city_ids

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Agencies" do
      f.input :picture, as: :file
      f.input :creation_date, label: 'Creation Date'
      f.input :name, label: 'Name'
      f.input :cities, as: :check_boxes, checked: City.pluck(&:id) # this will allow you to check the city names that you want to associate with the agency
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow you to associate the selected cities to the corresponding agency without creating (duplicating) new cities in the database. I think this is what you are looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the generated html that the option values in the city select input are the name of the city (not the id). 
Try this way: `collection: City.all.map{ |u| [u.name, u.id]}`

Some reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: With `collection: City.all.map{ |u| [u.name, u.id]}`

The option values are the id, not the name of the city.
When I update the agency with a city, the entry is still duplicated but the new entry has this html

`<option value="3">1</option>` (I suppose 1 is the id of the duplicated entry)

The problem is probably in the line of code you mentionned, I'll work on it, thank you